# Column ambiguously defined Error on Creating a view

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a view with below query.

```
SELECT the_day, t1, t2
  FROM year_days
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT tea_prodcution_date, SUM(quantity) t1
                  FROM TEA_PRODUCTION
                  WHERE field_name like 'T1'
               GROUP BY tea_prodcution_date) ON the_day = tea_prodcution_date
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT tea_prodcution_date, SUM(quantity) t2
                  FROM TEA_PRODUCTION
                  WHERE field_name like 'T2'
               GROUP BY tea_prodcution_date) ON the_day = tea_prodcution_date
 ORDER BY the_day
```

**year_days** is a view created with below query.

```
SELECT add_months(TRUNC(sysdate - (365), 'YYYY'),to_number(to_char(sysdate,'mm'))) + (level - 1) AS the_day
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <=
           to_number(TO_CHAR(last_day(add_months(TRUNC(sysdate, 'YYYY'), 11)),
                             'DDD'))
```

When i'm trying to execute my first query to create a view, i got below error.

```
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 58
```

Error occurs from `ON the_day = tea_prodcution_date` line.

how could i correct this error and create above view ?

Answer (score 1):

I found error with my query. query should correct as below.

```
SELECT the_day, t1, t2
  FROM year_days
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT tea_prodcution_date, SUM(quantity) t1
                  FROM TEA_PRODUCTION
                  WHERE field_name like 'T1'
               GROUP BY tea_prodcution_date) aa ON the_day = aa.tea_prodcution_date
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT tea_prodcution_date, SUM(quantity) t2
                  FROM TEA_PRODUCTION
                  WHERE field_name like 'T2'
               GROUP BY tea_prodcution_date) bb ON the_day = bb.tea_prodcution_date
 ORDER BY the_day
```

Comment: You're good to go, until someone adds a column named t1 to the year_days view, and this same exception will be raised again.  It's a REALLY, REALLY good idea to qualify ALL of the columns in your query, to protect it from breaking when someone adds a column.